# Select columns with a partial string variable

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with columns named like

```
x <- c("30 days Death Rates from Heart Attack", "30 days Death Rates from Pneumonia")
```

I have a variable to pass to a function, which selects the respective columns and perform certain calculation. The variable contains the key phrase, like "heart attack" or "pneumonia" but not the whole column name. I'm wondering if there is a way to select the column with such a variable.

I tried to use `$`, and it does not work. I have tried using `[]` or `[[]]`, but it says "undefined columns selected". How should I do it?

Comment: try `agrep(y[1], tolower(x))` or `pmatch` for simpler cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
pat <- "((?i)(h)eart (?i)(a)ttack|(?i)(p)neumonia)"
df1[grep(pat, names(df1))]
```